# How can i calculate price from discount given by supplier in a purchase order?

Tags: math, logic, discount

I have a sample value as shown below

```
$item_A = $ 112.50 @ 6% tax after tax = 9.25
$item_B = $ 10.00 @ 0% tax

//I bought 2 item_A ($ 238.50) and 1 item_B ($ 10)

$sub_total = $ 235.00
$tax_amt = $ 13.50
$total = $ 248.50
```

At here i want to apply a discount $40 and then share among on the items price, which mean my total should be $208.75 after discounted.

> discount will be based on setting either applied before or after tax of total amount

```
// formula to share among
$distribute = sub-total of item / total amount * discount
```

After get the $distribute, then will divide the quantity and add to the current unit price.

In this case, if i am recalculating the total amount, it will became lesser due to the unit price of item applied the discount.

My expected result is when applied $40 discount on $248.50, it will became $208.50 with a $40 discount applied even recalculate it.

is it need to remain the tax amount of the original price?

What is the solution to use to deal with this situation? Anyone can help and give suggestion on this case? Thanks.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Consider providing many more examples, with input and expected output. If there are enough, guessing at what you mean might become possible. Also, please remember that this is a community for programming problems. Please provide enough context, e.g. the programming language you are using, to turn this into such a programming question. You are also expected to show some own effort. Please show the program you have, which at least has all the input in suitable variables and can output a result (even if the result is wrong).

Comment: Note that due to how rounding works, you can easily get a total that is off by a few cents.